# how to use function in systemverilog?

Tags: system-verilog

I found sentencenlike this.

```
function device check_device ;
        case  ..
```

in system verilog code.

The device are consist of enum typedef.
 Also check _device is nothing.

Does anyone know what is it? Could you please explain this?

Also Why does  -> event exist except @?
What are different between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the code snippet, **check_device** is the **name of the function** you are defining. It would return a value of type **device**, which as you said is **typedef**ed as an **enum** definition.

In SystemVerilog, you can declare an explicit event and wait on that. The operator **->** is used to trigger an explicit event. Operator **@**, as in Verilog, is there to let you wait for an event.

For example:

```
class Foo;
  event bar;
  // ...
  function void notify_bar;
    ->bar;
  endfunction;
  task wait_for_bar;
    @bar;
  endtask;
endclass
```

Comment: Thanks so much again. Now I am refering here http://www.asic-world.com/systemverilog/sema_mail_events3.html would you please let me know how does result step out step by step. I can't understand the result order.

Comment: bang - ask as another question